# Probability two (specific) independent Markov chains are some time at the same state

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $\{X_n\},~\{Y_n\}$ be two independent Markov chains, with state space $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, both with transition probability matrix: $$\displaystyle P=\left(
>   \begin{array}{ccccccc}
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1/4 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 &  1/2 &  0&  0 & 1/2   \\
>  0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
>  \end{array}
> \right).$$
>   If initial  states $X_0\neq Y_0$ on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are given, 
>   find the probability that $X_n=Y_n$ for some $n$.

**Attempt.** I thought of working on $Z_n=X_n-Y_n,~n\geq 1$, and find $P(T<+\infty~|~Z=z_0),$ where $T=\inf\{k\geq 0:~Z_n=0\}$, but working with $\{Z_n\}$ doesns't seem a good choice (in terms of calculations).

Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Thank you in advance!

Edit. As @Did mentioned, if $X_0\neq Y_0$, the chains can not be indentically distributed.

Comment: If $X_0\ne Y_0$, the Markov chains $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ cannot be "iid".

Comment: Re the exercise itself, you are supposed to use a theorem from your notes that has the word "aperiodic" in it, to show that $T$ is finite almost surely.

Comment: If $\{X_n\}$ is irreducible, positively recurrent and aperiodic, then $\pi_n \rightarrow \pi$, where $\pi_n,~\pi$ denote the distribution of $X_n$ and the invariant distribution, respectively. But how is this connected to our question?

Comment: What do you know about the process $(W_n)$ defined by $W_n=(X_n,Y_n)$?

Comment: Did you want to find the probability that there exists an $n > 0$ such that $X_n = Y_n$, or did you want to find the probability, given $n$, that $X_n = Y_n$?  The latter depends on $X_0$ and $Y_0$ and seems rather more involved.

Comment: @BrianTung, I want to find the probability that there exists an n>0 such that $X_n=Y_n.$

Comment: The probability is 1, such an $n$ exists almost surely, because the Markov chain is aperiodic. I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout: given my answer and the comment (+downvotes !) received, can you please clearify what you mean by " I want to find the probability that there exists an n>0 such that $X_n=Y_n$"?. What do you mean by $X_n=Y_n$ ? that the probability vectors be equal ? or that $X$ and $Y$ be in the same state ($1,2, ...$) at step $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a clarification on the actual meaning of the question posed, and considering
the comments given and received, let's put the answer under three possible hypotheses.

1. *Probability that at step $n$ the two chains are in the same given state = $m$*
   Given the probability vectors
   $$
   \mathbf{X}_{\,n}  = \overline {\mathbf{P}} ^{\,n} \,\mathbf{X}_{\,0}  = \left\| {\,x_{\,m}^{\left( n \right)} \,} \right\|\quad \mathbf{Y}_{\,n}  = \overline {\mathbf{P}} ^{\,n} \,\mathbf{Y}_{\,0}  = \left\| {\,y_{\,m}^{\left( n \right)} \,} \right\|
   $$
   then the probability that the two chains, at step $n$  be in the same state $m$ is by definition
   $$
   p(n,m) = x_{\,m}^{\left( n \right)} y_{\,m}^{\left( n \right)} \quad \left| {\;1 \leqslant m \leqslant 5} \right.
   $$
   where $i$ and $j$ denote the starting state for $X$ and $Y$.
   For this probability to be non-null, the two corresponding entries in $ \mathbf{P} ^{\,n}$ must be non-null, at the same $n$:
   this is a double condition, which is related to the *irreducibility* and *regularity* of $ \mathbf{P} $.
   Now, the given matrix can be permuted as to get
   $$
   \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    \end{array} } \right)\;\overline {\mathbf{P}} \;\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    \end{array} } \right)\; = \left( {\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
      0 & 0 & 0 & &  0 & {1/4}  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & &  0 & {1/4}  \\
      0 & 0 & 0 & &  {1/2} & {1/4}  \\
   \hline
      0 & 0 & {1/2} & &  0 & {1/4}  \\
      1 & 1 & {1/2} & &  {1/2} & 0  \\
    \end{array} } \right)
   $$
   thus it is irreducible, and it becomes fully positive for $4 \leqslant n$.
   It is therefore a matter to compute the 2nd and 3rd power to see for which combination of the initial states 
   ($i,j$) and final state ($m$) it is null.
2. *Probability that at step $n$ the two chains are in the same state (whichever)*
   From the results above, we will clearly have that:
   $$
   \begin{gathered}
     p^ *  (n) = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,m} {p(n,k)}  = \mathbf{X}_{\,n}  \cdot \mathbf{Y}_{\,n}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,m} {P_{\,i\,,\,k}^{\left( n \right)} \,P_{\,k\,,\,j}^{\left( n \right)} }  =  \hfill \\
      = \overline {\mathbf{X}_{\,0} } \;\mathbf{P}^{\,n} \;\overline {\mathbf{P}} ^{\,n} \;\mathbf{Y}_{\,0} \,\quad \left| {\;1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant 5} \right. \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered} 
   $$
   and since $\overline{\mathbf{P}}$ can be permuted into the block partition already shown
   it is easy to get that the product matrix is fully positive already for $n=2$.
3. *Probability that at step $n$ the two chains have the same probability to be in each of the possible states*
   i.e. that they have the same probability vector.
   $$
   \mathbf{X}_n  = \overline {\mathbf{P}}^{\,n} \,\mathbf{X}_0  = \mathbf{Y}_n  = \overline {\mathbf{P}}^{\,n} \,\mathbf{Y}_0 \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{0} = \overline {\mathbf{P}}^{\,n} \left( {\mathbf{X}_0  - \mathbf{Y}_0 } \right)
   $$
   where $\overline {\mathbf{P}} $ indicates the transpose of $\mathbf{P}$.
   Now it is easy to get that the nullspace of $ \overline{\mathbf{P}}$ is given by $(1,\, 0,\, -1,\, 0,\, 0)$.
   Of course,  that is also the nullspace of $  \overline {\mathbf{P}}^{\,n}$, and viceversa the nullspace of $  \overline{\mathbf{P}}^{\,n}$
   cannot be other than that, for whichever $1 \leqslant n$.
   Therefore
   $$
   \left( {\mathbf{X}_0  - \mathbf{Y}_0 } \right) = \lambda \;\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
      1  \\   0  \\   { - 1}  \\   0  \\   0  \\
    \end{array} } \right)\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \mathbf{X}_n  = \mathbf{Y}_n \quad \left| \begin{gathered}
     \;\lambda \; \in \;\;\mathbb{R}\,\, \hfill \\
     \;1 \leqslant \forall n \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   $$
   So we are looking for the couples of vectors $(\mathbf X, \, \mathbf Y)$ such that
   $$
   \left\{ \begin{gathered}
     1 \leqslant x_{\,k} ,y_{\,k}  \leqslant 5 \hfill \\
     \lambda  \in \;\;\mathbb{Z}\, \hfill \\
     x_{\,1}  - y_{\,1}  = \lambda  \hfill \\
     x_{\,3}  - y_{\,3}  =  - \lambda  \hfill \\
     x_{\,2}  = y_{\,2} ,\quad x_{\,4}  = y_{\,4} ,\quad x_{\,5}  = y_{\,5}  \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered}  \right.
   $$
   By drawing the line $y=x+\lambda$ within a square $(1, \cdots, 5) \times (1, \cdots, 5)$
   we can realize that the 2nd identity above has $5^2$ solutions, each associated with a solution to the 3rd id.
   Thus the number of the couples of vectors satisfying the conditions will be:
   $$
   5^{\,2}  \cdot 5^{\,3}  = 5^{\,5} 
   $$
   versus a total of $5^{10}$.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, then the question is to calculate the probability that $X$ and $Y$ have the same state at some time $n$. You're comparing the probability vectors $X_n$ and $Y_n$.

Comment: @Paul: yes, I have a doubt about interpreting the question. If it is like you put, then at time $n$ the probability that X and Y have the same state would be just $p=\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i Y_i$, i.e. the dot product of the vectors, i.e the quadric with $\overline {\mathbf{P}} ^{\,n} \mathbf{P} ^{\,n}$, so what is the question there ?

Comment: +1, partly compensatory.  Seems to add value and was an honest attempt.

Comment: @BrianTung: thanks for the appreciation, but waiting for **a much due** clarification by the OP (re. my comment above), what is your interpretation of what we shall *attempt* to answer, actually ?  P.S.: I would much like that the downvoters were also honest in dropping a line to motivate their dissense !!

Comment: @GCab: I *think* the question is asking for the probability that there exists some moment in time at which the two Markov chains are in the same state.  As Did observes in the comments to the OP, this happens almost surely.  P.S. to your P.S.  Good luck with that.  I'd like a million dollars, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine any two Markov chains to make a new Markov chain.

If we combine $X$ and $Y$, we get a Markov chain with state space $\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),\dots,(5,4),(5,5)\}$ and initial state $(X_0,Y_0)$. Let's call this Markov chain $W$.

Since we have 25 states, the transition matrix $P_W$ of $W$ will be of size $25 \times 25$. The probability of going from, for example, state $(1,2)$ to state $(3,4)$ will simply be the probability of going from 1 to 3 in the first chain multiplied by the probability of going from 2 to 4 in the second chain. You may want to construct the matrix with a computer program such as Mathematica.

The probability of being in a certain state can be calculated as usual:

$W_n = ({P_W}^\mathrm{T})^n W_0$,

where $W_0$ is the initial probability of the states, in your case a vector with one of the elements equal to 1 and the other 24 equal to 0. Now we can do:

$P(X_n = Y_n) = \sum_{i=1}^5 P(W_n=(i,i)) = wW_n$,

where $w = (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$

Comment: It seems like I answered the wrong question. This is if you want to calculate for a specific $n$ the probability that $X$ and $Y$ are in the same state.

Comment: I've overcomplicated things. As G Cab commented on his answer, the probability that $X$ and $Y$ have the same state would be just $p = \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i Y_i$